# Range Autofill one row down only using variable preferrably

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to select the last row from B to Z only (that's the only row that has formulas in it.)
This range should autofill only one row down and make the second last row values only (meaning remove formulas). So the last row should always have formulas in it.

a dataset that looks like this:

```
    A B C ..... Z
1   1 2 2 ......26
2   1 2 2 ......26
3   1 2 2 ......26
4   1 2 2 ......26
5   1 2 2 ......26
```

So the code should select from B5:Z5 and autofill down one row.

I have tried the following code and it gives me a runtime error.

```
Sub autofilllastrow()

Dim Lastrow As Integer
Dim Lastrange As Range


Lastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Range("B" & Lastrow, "Z" & Lastrow).Select

Lastrange.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B" & Lastrow + 1, "Z" & Lastrow + 1)


End Sub
```

How should I properly define the Destination part and make the second last row values only?

Comment: You never assign anything to `Lastrange`, so it stays `Nothing`, this will give you a runtime error

Comment: right, I forgot to assign something to Lastrange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub autofilllastrow()

Dim lr As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Cells(lr + 1, 2), .Cells(lr + 1, 26)).FillDown
    .Range(.Cells(lr, 2), .Cells(lr, 26)).Value = .Range(.Cells(lr, 2), .Cells(lr, 26)).Value
End With

End Sub
```

- Without the use of `.Select`
- With `Long` data type instead of `Integer`
- `FillDown` instead of `AutoFill`

Or if you are keen on setting a `Range` variable:

```
Sub autofilllastrow()

Dim lr As Long, rng As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(lr, 2), .Cells(lr, 26))
    rng.Offset(1).FillDown
    rng.Value = rng.Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This works perfectly. It looks so simple, for you at least :) Just one question, why did you use Long instead of Integer? Lr just returns a row number.

Comment: @purpleblau, because there simply is no use for `Integer`. A `Long` datatype will do anything `Integer` does but "better". Meaning it's more error-proof since `Integer` can overflow more easily. So my advise is that you should get in the habit of using `Long` instead.

Comment: Btw, glad it worked for you =). Consider to accept as answer to return the favor.

Comment: you bet, favor returned, thanks a bunch. That row number is just from 1 to 1Mio in Excel. Using Long is kinda overkill in my opinion, and it requires more ram. Just my 2 cent.